# Asp.NET Web API 2.0: Keywords to create API documentation

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, documentation

I am developing a Web.API 2.0 with Visual Studio 2013. It generates a html documentation page automatically from the documentation of the controller methods like:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// general description of the method
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">URI parameter</param>
    /// <returns>response information</returns>
```

In the html-page of the automatically created documentation is also a section called **[Body Parameters]**. What keywords do I have to use in the method documentation to make it displayed in the Body Parameters section?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

just enter three /// on top of the web method